# Multiple ng-app sharing ng-view and $route

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, route-provider, ng-view

I have an MVC application with Header and Content using Angularjs.

I have defined an ng-app in Content and load the content pages using $routeProvider. This is working fine.

I have a link in Header from where I want to show a page in Content area - this is outside of the ng-app. How can I do this without setting ng-app at the top ? Also suggest if there is some other way to accomplish the same, as many Master page websites are built around this UI design only.

Below is my code showing Master.cshtml and app.js. Let me know incase I need to provide some more code -

Master.cshtml -

```
@inherits WebViewPage

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.PageTitle</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angularjs/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <li><a ng-href="#/headerLinkPage1">View cart</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="rootApp">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js -

```
var serviceBaseAddress = 'http://localhost/MyWebApi/api/';

var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['ngRoute', 'contentPage1', 'headerLinkPage1'])

.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/contentPage1', {
            templateUrl: '../ContentPage1/Index'
        }).
        when('/headerLinkPage1', {
            templateUrl: '../HeaderLinkPage1/Index'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/contentPage1'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Why do you not want to set ng-app at the top of the html page? This way you can use a directive to create a header on each page and give certain information from each page to the header directive.

Comment: Because my website will have 5 modules with 10 pages each. And i want to create 5 ng-app to handle and load them separately. There are some links in the Header that I wanted to load in the existing ng-app ng-view rather than creating a new ng-app. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Read the documentation of ngApp: Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. So what are you trying to do.

Comment: Thats correct @Ved. What is also feasible and correct is to put "<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="xxxx"> <div ng-view></div> </div>" in other multiple htmls say mainAppPage1.html, mainAppPage2.html, mainAppPage3.html, mainAppPage4.html, mainAppPage5.html each with different ng-app="xxxx" and then use $routeProvider to load in ng-view.

Comment: You can load multiple page inside ng-view without having multiple ng-app.

Comment: @Ved - You are not getting my Question and my Comments. Let others respond please. I will explain further if anybody else also have some queries.

Comment: @AmanpreetSingh Hope anyone will understand your isuue. All the best..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want modularity in your angular routes, you can use ui router to achieve this, I basically created a main app called `app` and then two sub apps called `app1` and `app2`, try http://plnkr.co/edit/sk5EmMWQgcIfYlOteWtt , Let me know if thats not what you are looking for

```
(function() {

  angular.module('app1', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('app1', {
          url: '/app1',
          abstract: true,
          template: '<div ui-view="app1View"></div>'
        })
        .state('app1.child1', {
          url: '/child1',
          views: {
            'app1View' : {
              template: '<div>child 1, app 1</div>'
            }
          }
        })
    })

})();


(function() {

  angular.module('app2', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('app2', {
          url: '/app2',
          abstract: true,
          template: '<div ui-view="app2View"></div>'
        })
        .state('app2.child1', {
          url: '/child1',
          views: {
            'app2View' : {
              template: '<div>child 1, app 2</div>'
            }
          }
        })
    })

})();
```

So this way your sub modules `app1` and `app2` are completely independent of each other and you can add or remove more sub modules or sub routes within each of these sub modules

Comment: I want a setup, where My main angular app is divided into 5 different sub-apps, according to feature. I want to define routing info for each of sub-app seperately in their .config() method, so that routeConfig info. of one app doesn't clash with other app and code is easy to maintain, rather than putting all routingConfig info in myApp. Moreover, I am not able to access plnkr link given by you. Jsfiddle will be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that functionality.

Comment: In layman's term, can you explain me the difference between stateprovider and routeProvider ? And when to use each of them ? Advantages and disadvantages of each ?

Comment: Moreover, Plnkr doesn't open properly in my machine. Can you create this eg. in jsfiddle so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: stateProvider is a part of ui-router, which itself is a much more powerful alternative to angulars inbuilt router

Comment: Good Answer, @user2393267 I can open the link, can you try other browsers?